# Unknown provider: FIREBASE_URLProvider <- FIREBASE_URL <- Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire, ionic-framework

**The full error** 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FIREBASE_URLProvider <- FIREBASE_URL <- Post

The local server spun up a working app just a couple of days ago. Now when I start it, app is blank and throws up this error. Anyone knows the issue?

Im following a online lesson and perhaps the versions are outdated?

The error link leads to this page. [ERROR LINK PAGE IN ANGULARJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=FIREBASE_URLProvider%20%3C-%20FIREBASE_URL%20%3C-%20Post) but my definitions are ok since they were working previously?

**Attached is my index.html scripts.**

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- <script src="vendor/someContribJs.js"></script> -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <!--all the scripts for the app --> 
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I had another Var X = angular.module(myapp, []) line hidden somewhere in the app.js codes. 
Not sure how it got there but removing that did the trick. So the error message was correct.

Comment: Great! Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: DOnt worry @Fedaykin, appreciate your kindness :)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but try placing the angularfire.js script before the firebase-simple-login.js

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ionic/release/js/ionic-angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularfire/angularfire.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/firebase-simple-login/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
```

Another guess would be to check if there is a missing configuration concerning the firebase url.

Comment: Tried, shifting around doesnt work. I also tried putting all angular stuff together with the app scripts...no work too :(  Problem is it was working just fine a few days ago and i didnt change any codes. Did they update the angularfire stuff or firebase?

Comment: Thanks @Fedaykin how do i check for missing configuration concerning the firebase url?